# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str in Global terrorism dataset

Tags: python, data-science, exploratory-data-analysis

`filterYear = data['Year'] == 1970`

I am getting an error of

1 filterYear = data['Year'] == 1970

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

I tried to see the datatype of the series and its numeric.

I am at a loss

Answer (score 0):

Without a fuller selection of code that you're trying (unsuccessfully) to run, it's hard to be sure of just where your bug lies, but I suspect your `data` is a `list`, of the type:

```
data = [thing1, thing2, thing3, etc.]
```

If so, then to retrieve `thing2` from `data`, you must index it using an integer representing the position of `thing2` in `data`, like so: `data[1]`.

The string `'Year'` is not an integer, and so cannot be used to identify which member of the list `data` you are trying to retrieve - which leads to the error you've encountered.

If you wished to store data with labels, you might want to consider using a `dict`:

```
dict1 = {'label1' : 'thing1', 'label2' : 'thing2'}
```

Set up in this way, if you invoked `dict1['label1']`, you would obtain `'thing1'`.

Like I said, a fuller description of both your code, and precisely what you're trying to achieve, would help formulate a more helpful response.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your index is not a DatTimeIndex. Check with `print(data.index)`. You can set the index with `data = data.set_index('name_of_column_with_data')`. Please show a sample of your DataFrame for further help.

(assuming you are using pandas, not clear from your question)

Answer (score 0):

This type of error occurs when indexing a list with anything other than integers or slices, as the error mentions. Usually, the most straightforward method for solving this problem is to convert any relevant values to integer type using the int() function. Something else to watch out for is accidentally using list values to index a list, which also gives us the type error.